# Excel 2007: AVERAGEIF, SUMIF, COUNTIF, MAXIF, MINIF across multiple sheets, multple rows

Tags: excel, function, pivot, formula, array-formulas

@MGonet - I am very much appreciative for the answer you gave, and also the idea to use /COUNT as an alternative denominator (which I have decided to do). I have run into two different problems, though, and would appreciate if you (or anyone else) could possibly expand on this a little more with this added information.

Problem #1:
All 12 sheets from January:December contain SOME blank cells in M5:M100, and several sheets have no data at all in M5:M100. These cells populate a result when numerical data is entered into G and H in the respective sheets. The following formula is used in M5:M100 on all 12 sheets.

```
=IFERROR((H5-G5)/ABS(G5),"")
```

This formula is to hide the "#DIV/0" error that is shown when values are not yet present in G and H.

As a side note, I am applying some of your formulas to N5:N100 as well, which contains the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(H5="",G5="",J5=""),"",(H5-G5)*(J5))
```

Likewise, this formula is to hide the 0's that populate with an empty currency-formatted cell.

When I evaluate the "=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT" formula, I notice that if a sheet has ANY data in M5:M100 (or N5:N100), it will populate a numeric value for that sheet. For the sheets that do not have any data in M5:M100 (or N5:N100), it returns "#DIV/0" for those, and causes the formula to error with "#DIV/0." I'm assuming there is a value that can be worked into the formula to ignore the blank cells, but I still need to be able to maintain the >0 or <0 criteria within the formula, in addition to ignoring the blank cells.

Problem #2:
With ANY of the provided formulas that contain "IF" (the first 6), Excel immediately crashes when I enter a value into G or H, but only in a sheet for February:December. It does not crash when I enter values into the January sheet. I think I have somewhat isolated this to the "=IFERROR" and "=IF" functions that I am using to show a blank cell for M and N respectively. If I remove the formulas from those cells, Excel does not crash when entering data into G and H. I imagine it has something to do with an IF formula running into another IF formula, but I'm no Excel guru, I'm quite the opposite.

Problem #2 doesn't seem like any issue concerning the functionality of the formulas you've provided, but I wonder if there is another way to hide "#DIV/0" for the M cells and the "0" populated in the N cells (formatted for currency), to avoid whatever this conflict is with those formulas.

I hope this is a little bit clearer than my earlier edit. Let me know, thanks.

===================

Good day, folks.

I have spent the past 3 days and nights trying to work this formula out, and alas, I am at my wits end.
I have a workbook with 13 sheets, January:December, and one named "Trade Statistics." January:December all have identical columns, but different data values. I need to be able to perform the "IF" function for Average, Sum, Count, Min, and Max functions. As I have come to learn, "IF" functions do not work directly across multiple spreadsheets. I have tried a name range with INDIRECT formulas, but when using "N" it only returns results for the first row, regardless of if I specify a cell range. I am using these functions to determine a multitude of stats, so I need to be able to imply <0 and >0 as conditions. See the attached image. I have read other topics, but none seem to quite match exactly what I'm trying to accomplish here, and I'm no expert in Excel.

([Trade Statistics Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SfnK.jpg))

More specifically, I need to be able to convert the following formulas to work across multiple sheets and rows (to correctly identify values in the YEARLY, as shown in the image):

```
=AVERAGEIF(January!$M$5:$M$100,">0",January!$M$5:$M$100)
=AVERAGEIF(January!$M$5:$M$100,"<0",January!$M$5:$M$100)
=SUM(IF(January!$N$5:$N$100>0,January!$N$5:$N$100))
=SUM(IF(January!$N$5:$N$100<0,January!$N$5:$N$100))
=COUNTIF(January!$M$5:$M$100,">0")/COUNT(January!$M$5:$M$100)
=COUNTIF(January!$M$5:$M$100,"<0")/COUNT(January!$M$5:$M$100)
=MIN(IF(January!$M$5:$M$100>0,January!$M$5:$M$100))
=MAX(IF(January!$M$5:$M$100<0,January!$M$5:$M$100))
```

I very much appreciate and look forward to any possible solutions that I (hopefully) haven't already tried. This is being done in Excel 2007, so I am limited to the features thereof.

Comment: Frankly, the issues you face here are a direct result of your decision to split the data across multiple sheets.  I'd suggest you either: 1) permanently consolidate the data onto a single sheet, or 2) create a summary sheet that pulls all data onto a single sheet, possibly using the Get Data features (I haven't used Excel 2007 for over a decade, so can't advise on that specific version)

Comment: There's far too much additional data on the sheets (not part of the calculations) to allow for a one sheet solution. This is to summarize statistics on data gradually collected throughout the year.

Comment: You added something there, but now you deleted it and I don't know what to refer to.
As you can see, all the details are important, and Excel has its whims.
If you're having problems with `IFERROR` function, try using an older version:
`=IF(ISERROR(expression),"",expression)`
I also still have the 2007 version on my old computer, but I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry - I noticed that I was mistaken about some of the info I gave earlier, and didn't want to confuse things. I removed the edit and comment until I could explain better. I will attempt to explain it again now that I've had time to look deeper into it. I will edit the original question again shortly.

Comment: re _There's far too much additional data on the sheets (not part of the calculations) to allow for a one sheet solution_ : well, consider my option 2 to consolidate the relavent data

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will move towards your suggestion if I continue to have issues, ultimately, as long as the task gets completed and the data is visible in a professional looking manner, that's all I'm after. Though, judging by MGonet's response, the issue with my software crashing may be an isolated issue. I had to rebuild the entire work book this past weekend because the cells would no longer update when data was entered, regardless of the formula...so it seems I may have some other underlying issues here. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify for this issue, that some of the odd problems that were discussed here were a direct cause of corrupted files within my Office 2007 suite. After upgrading to Office 2021, I was able to implement the suggestions made here without any trouble. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four:

```
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),">0"))
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),"<0"))
=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!N5:N100"),">0"))
=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!N5:N100"),"<0"))
```

The next two (if you expect one total value for a year):

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),">0"))/SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),"<>"))
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),"<0"))/SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),"<>"))
```

The condition `"<>"` means any non-empty cell. If you want to count only numbers you should use `">-1E10"` with a suitably big negative number (depends on values you use).
Or instead of these denominators you can use:

```
COUNT(January:December!$M$5:$M$100)
```

It counts only numbers.

The last two:

```
=SMALL(January:December!$M$5:$M$100,INDEX(FREQUENCY(January:December!$M$5:$M$100,0),1,1)+1)
=SMALL(January:December!$M$5:$M$100,INDEX(FREQUENCY(January:December!$M$5:$M$100,-0.0001),1,1))
```

***Edit after completing the question***

Problem #1
I don't know of a simple way to mask the error (especially in the rather old version of 2007) other than to use some form of conditional statement.
Any operation on an erroneous data propagates an error. Instead of `IFERROR`, you can use the `IF` function with an `ISERROR` condition or other test that specifies the conditions for an error to occur. For example, instead of:
`=IFERROR((H5-G5)/ABS(G5),"")`
you can write:
`=IF(G5, (H5-G5)/ABS(G5), "")` (providing that in `G5` is number or it is empty).
When calculating the average, it would be necessary to specify whether it is the average of the monthly averages or the average of all readings that meet the condition (their number may vary from month to month).

If we calculate the average from the averages and in some month the average cannot be calculated, again we can only use the conditional function to catch such a case. The average must then be calculated as the quotient of the sum of the available values by the number of these values

```
=SUM(IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&”!M5:M100”),">0"),0))/COUNT(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&”!M5:M100”),">0"))
```

Or with `ISERROR`

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&”!M5:M100”),">0"),0, AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&”!M5:M100”),">0")))/COUNT(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&”!M5:M100”),">0"))
```

Problem #2
As I wrote in the comment, I can only see the possibility of replacing `IFERROR` with another `IF` expression. I don't understand why Excel keeps crashing for you.

***In relation to OP's comment***
I don't really understand this problem with `#DIV/0!`
The screen shows different use cases for the `AVERAGEIF` function. Which case is this?
This is Polish version of Excel: `#DZIEL/0!` means `#DIV/0!`
[image: AVERAGEIF]

Comment: Thank you for detailing your answer for me. I seem to have caught the flu, so I haven't been up much to work on it lately. I will definitely try your recommendation, and I am considering a reinstall of my software (or possibly just upgrade)...I had an issue where all of the formulas in the workbook quit responding this past weekend and I had to rebuild it. I think I isolated that to some clipart/images that were being used in the sheets, but I spent hours trying to make it work before rebuilding it completely. Again, thanks.

Comment: I could not figure out how to get around the `#DIV/0!` error and still be able to specify greater than or less than 0 for the `AVERAGEIF` functions. Only if I specified `<>` it would ignore zero and blanks, but then returned the entire range of negative and positives, and the average of those together. I will be updating my question with the solutions I have used (now working in Excel 2021, after upgrading from 2007, but I believe they share the same compatibility in reference to these formulas).

Answer (score 0):

With much help from @MGonet and a consolidation idea from @chris-neilsen, I used the following formulas and process to accomplish my tasks across multiple spreadsheets.

I created a sheet named "Sheets" and added a Name Range from A1 through A12 to it with each month of the year (name of each spreadsheet), in order to use INDIRECT with "IF" containing functions. I used the following to find the statistics over 12 spreadsheets/months. I used CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to commit each formula:

Annual $ P/L

```
=SUM(January:December!$N$5:$N$100)
```

Annual $ PROFIT

```
=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!N5:N100"),">0"))
```

Annual $ LOSS

```
=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!N5:N100"),"<0"))
```

Annual %WIN

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),">0"))/COUNT(January:December!$M$5:$M$100)
```

Annual %LOSS

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),"<0"))/COUNT(January:December!$M$5:$M$100)
```

Smallest % GAIN

```
=SMALL(January:December!$M$5:$M$100,INDEX(FREQUENCY(January:December!$M$5:$M$100,0),1,1)+1)
```

Smallest % LOSS

```
=SMALL(January:December!$M$5:$M$100,INDEX(FREQUENCY(January:December!$M$5:$M$100,-0.0001),1,1))
```

Biggest % GAIN

```
=MAX(January:December!$M$5:$M$100)
```

Bigest % LOSS

```
=MIN(January:December!$M$5:$M$100)
```

Average % GAIN

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),">0"),""))
```

Average % LOSS

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),"<0"),""))
```

Average $ GAIN

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!N5:N100"),">0"),""))
```

Average $ LOSS

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!N5:N100"),"<0"),""))
```

Thanks again for the help! It took me all week to get here, but I couldn't have done it without you guys! :)

Comment: I'm glad you managed. In my opinion, these extra cells are not necessary, but I can't see your data. A picture is better than 1000 words, and a file is even better. But there are troubles with that on this forum.
Why the sequence doesn't work:
`AVERAGE(IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT...` ?

Comment: @MGonet - Yep, you got it. That's the winning combination. ```=AVERAGE(IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT(Sheets!$A$1:$A$12&"!M5:M100"),"<0"),""))```So I will edit my last post to remove the process of adding columns and such... I knew there had to be a way to simplify that...just not good enough with it myself to put it together. Thanks again!